# Mac command - check free space on USB?

Tags: macos, shell

I have to check a lot of usb's, all of them should have the same files on it. But because I am a windows user I don't know how to do the following automatically on mac (like a batch on windows):

- Check free space on the device
- Give out if its equal to a value
- Eject the device

Is this even possible on mac?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you want to do it ? I mean from command line or you want to use GUI. I ask this as you mentioned that you used Windows before.

Comment: Like a batch on windows, i don't know much about how this works on mac

Comment: If GUI, connect the USB to the Mac. If detected , check if it gets mounted and appears on the desktop. By behavior, it should! If it doesn't you may have to install ntfs-3g in case your USBs have ntfs file system. If it's detected, just right click on the drive, Click on "Get Info" to get disk space related information. In order to eject it, just right click on it and click on "Eject". I didn't understand your second point. Do you mind elaborating it ?

Comment: Hmm . if you want something similar like a batch for it, you may consider writing a shell script and executing it to get the info. Use "df -h" to get the disk space information. "umount <device_name>" to eject the disks from /Volumes. You could also use "diskutil eject <path_to_disk>" to eject it.

Comment: Im sorry, i did a mistake in the question! I want to make something similar to a batch which does it automatically, i think it's possible with a windows batch but i don't know how to do it on mac.

Comment: lanzz has coded it what I mentioned up. Just customise it as per your convenience and get going :)

Comment: The problem is thats all new land for me, if i do something wrong and crash my mac then i'm in big trouble because it's not my mac. Is it true that already small typos can crass/destroy the os when running with 'sudo'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find free space in kilobytes using the `df` command:

```
df -k /Volumes/label | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

Since you will need to use that number, you'll need to assign it to a variable:

```
FREE=$(df -k /Volumes/Label | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $4 }')
```

Then you can compare it against another number:

```
if [ $FREE -eq 12345678 ]
then
    # matches
else
    # doesn't match
fi
```

And finally eject the volume:

```
umount /Volumes/Label
```

Note, however, that checking for free space is probably not the most robust approach. Flash drives from different manufacturers differ slightly in size, even if they're the same nominal capacity. Also flash memory degrades with use and defective blocks might get remapped to working ones, further reducing the total capacity of the drive. Even if you have the same contents, free space can differ.

If you actually have a template directory containing the files needed on the flash drive, you can compare it against the contents of the drive:

```
diff -qr /Volumes/Label /template/directory
```

This will print out all differences, but you can also take action based on whether there are differences, discarding the actual output from `diff`:

```
if diff -qr /Volumes/Label /template/directory > /dev/null
then
    # directories are the same
else
    # contents differ
fi
```

Manual pages:

[`df`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/df.1.html)
[`umount`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/umount.8.html)
[`diff`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/diff.1.html)
[Shell Scripting Primer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004268-TP40003516)

Comment: Thanks, they are all from the same manufacturer. Bu since im new to mac and don't want to type this in the terminal every time: How can i save it as a executable file?

Comment: I've added references to relevant manual pages. Check out the Shell Scripting Primer for an introduction on writing shell scripts.